# Looping output result

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to loop the rows to echo out my result. So i'm joining my 2 database tables to get some results, specifically model number and model name from the orders table while others from the order_history table. I'm trying to loop the rows so that it echos out the goods that are delivered at what time and by whom, as well as approved by whom. However, i seem to get an endless loop of result, can I have some advice on how to do my looping of result.These are the tables that I'm using-> [orders table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPnnJ.png) and [order_history table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHjmk.png). Thank You.

[EDIT] : [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpRqC.png)

```
  <?php

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM orders o
                              INNER JOIN order_history oh 
                              ON o.order_id = oh.order_id";
                    $result = $conn->query($query);
                    if(!$result) die($conn->error);
                    $rows = $result->num_rows;

                    if ($rows > 0) { 

                ?>
                        <table  id="tabledata" class=" table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">

                            <tr class="bg-dark text-white text-center">

                                <th> Order ID </th>
                                <th> Model Number </th>
                                <th> Model Name </th>
                                <th> Warehouse A </th>
                                <th> Storage Room </th>


                            </tr >
                <?php
                        // output data of each row
                        while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                ?>          
                            <tr>
                <?php
                        for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++){
                ?>
                                <td> <?php echo $rows['order_id'];  ?> </td>
                                <td> <?php echo $rows['model_number'];  ?> </td>
                                <td> <?php echo $rows['model_name'];  ?> </td>
                                <td> 
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Delivered by <?php echo $rows['deliverer'];  ?> at 
                                            <?php echo $rows['time_delivered'];  ?></li>
                                        <li><?php echo $rows['order_status'];  ?> by <?php echo $rows['approver'];  ?></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                                <td> 
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Delivered by <?php echo $rows['deliverer'];  ?> at 
                                        <?php echo $rows['time_delivered'];  ?></li>
                                        <li><?php echo $rows['order_status'];  ?> by <?php echo $rows['approver'];  ?></li>
                                   </ul>
                               </td>
                <?php
                        }
                ?>
                            </tr>
                <?php
                            }
                        }

                ?>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Why are you using for loop inside the rows, while is providing the row what you need

Comment: You shouldn't have a `for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++){` loop, the `while` loop iterates over all your results already.

Comment: But i need to loop out my results as under my station_name column in my order_history, the stations are different and I cannot echo them out in specific html table columns

Comment: It is not an endless loop, it is a nested loop -- which you do not need.

Comment: But how do I echo out the specific records into specific html columns? The station_name db column has different stations, and I am trying to echo it into different columns with their respective data

Comment: By using a "$group" variable which is instantiated as `null` but gets updated at the end of each loop.  You should clarify your question by providing your desired, rendered output.

Comment: You will need to adapt this exact technique to deliver your grouped html output: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697336/2943403 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020886/2943403 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/54205037/2943403

Answer (score 1):

use the following :-

```
<?php while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $rows['order_id'];  ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $rows['model_number'];  ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $rows['model_name'];  ?> </td>
<td align="center"> 
    <ul>
        <li>Delivered by <?php echo $rows['deliverer'];  ?> at 
            <?php echo $rows['time_delivered'];  ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $rows['order_status'];  ?> by <?php echo $rows['approver'];  ?></li>
    </ul>
</td>
<td align="center"> 
    <ul>
        <li>Delivered by <?php echo $rows['deliverer'];  ?> at <?php echo $rows['time_delivered'];  ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $rows['order_status'];  ?> by <?php echo $rows['approver'];  ?></li>
   </ul>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This solves half the problem, but it does not follow the html columns, as in under the warehouse A and storage room html column, it repeats the same thing and does not echo out properly

Comment: @heh can you please post the screenshot.

Comment: I posted the screenshot in the question post above

Comment: I am asking about, after updating your code what output you are getting I want to see that, as you mentioned that about HTML column

Comment: Yes I have posted the output as [EDIT] : error in the question post, sorry i didnt clarify this

Comment: use the <td align="center">, you can use margin-left property

Comment: As you can see in the image, under the warehouse A and Storage room column, they echo out the same thing proceed to echo out the other repeatedly on another row

Comment: Please avoid posting _use this_ answers.  Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: Ermm the output is still the same, just that they are centered. Is my way of echoing the result wrong? I want to echo records with station_name of warehouse A into the Warehouse A html column and Storage room station_name into the Storage Room html column. Is my query any faulty or the way I'm echoing the result wrong?

Comment: as i can understand from your table display, the dot is coming before the column line, in this case you can format it using the css